# How do I add User Input (String) into a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For some reason any user input isn't appended to the empty list.

```
list = []

print("Who wrote War and Peace?: ")
book1 = input()

for i in list:
    list.append(book1)
    print(f"Author: " + i)
```

Comment: change `book1 = input()` to `lst.append(input())`

Comment: it didn't get appended because `list` is empty, and there's no `i` to for loop with.

Comment: Don't name variables (`list`) after in-built python types/functions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, where the code says `for i in list:`, what exactly do you expect this to mean? How many times do you expect the loop to run, and why? (Hint: what does the list contain before the loop runs?) Also: please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. We are interested in *clear, specific questions*, [not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236) "I'm not sure where I'm going wrong".

Comment: Why are you doing `for i in list`? I don't see any reason to do that in the first place. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour].

Comment: @Nick More info for OP: `list` is a bad variable name since it [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the [builtin `list` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list). It's better to use a more descriptive name like `authors`, or at least something like `lst`. For an example of a problem you could get into, see [TypeError: 'list' object is not callable](/q/31087111/4518341).

Comment: @wjandrea thanks for adding that - I didn't have access to my appropriate canned comment...

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are trying to add an item to an empty list and using a for loop to access it but you are doing the opposite.

Another thing is you are using a formatted string to print the author's name. Remember when doing a formatted string, you use {} and just put the variable inside it instead of doing + variable

```
my_list = []

print("Who wrote War and Peace?: ")
book1 = input('')

my_list.append(book1)

for i in my_list:
    print(f"Author: {i}")
```

Answer (score -1):

When you print out the value of `list`, Python interprets this as the `list` data-types. You can fix your issue by changing the variable name to something like `l` or `my_list`.

On further notice, you are looping for every item in the list, but the list is empty, so the for-loop won't run.

Answer (score -1):

From my reproduction, there is no "i" value in list (its empty). Therefore the for loop is not triggering, nothing to loop over.

Reproduction:

```py
user_input=(input("\nWhat is the airspeed velocity of a (European) unladen swallow?: "))
a=False
list = []
for i in list:
    a=True #if For Loop is triggered a is True and prints pass
    list.append(user_input)
    print(list)
if a is not True: #if For loop is not triggered then fail will be printed
    print('fail')
else:
    print('pass')
```

Results

```
What is the airspeed velocity of a (European) unladen swallow?: 24 mph
fail
```

In order to append to the list. Remove the for loop for the initial input.

```
user_input1=(input("\nWhat is the airspeed velocity of a (European) unladen swallow?: \n"))
list_ = []
list_.append(user_input1)

user_input2=(input("We are the Knights who say?: \n"))
for i in range(len(list_)):
    list_.append(user_input2)
    print(list_)
```

Results

```
What is the airspeed velocity of a (European) unladen swallow?: 
24 mph
We are the Knights who say?: 
Ni
['24 mph', 'Ni']
```

As Neurotricity said dont use list as a variable for a list (I usually put a "_" at the end). (see their comment for more detail)

Comment: What's the point of `for i in range(len(list_))`? You can just `list_.append(user_input2)`.

Comment: To simplify the reproduction, you can just use a print, like `print('in loop')`, and you'll see that it never prints.